# Using existing enum in JHipster

Tags: java, enums, jhipster

When generating new Entity in JHipster, is it possible to add an existing enum?

For example java.time.DayOfWeek, currently a new enum file is generated.

Am I missing a flag or an option to generator?

Thank you!

Comment: No it's not possible

Comment: Any plan to add this feature? :)

Comment: Probably not as it seems trivial for the user to do it, see #2 in our policies https://jhipster.github.io/policies/ but you could open a feature request in github.

Answer (score 1):

When creating entities(2 or more), which is using the same enum(say Status with 'ACTIVE'/ 'INACTIVE'), each time we can type in the same enum and its values, and the *old enum will get replaced with the new enum*.

JHipster version used ("ng-jhipster": "0.2.7","generator-jhipster": "4.6.2", Spring Boot 1.5.4.RELEASE)